# How can I change my MinGW/MSYS + mintty home directory?

Tags: windows, mingw, msys, mintty

I use mintty as my console emulator for MinGW/MSYS.  Recently (I'm not certain exactly when), the home directory used by this combination changed from my Windows user folder (`/c/Users/<me>/`) to `/home/<me>/`, which is causing minor havoc for me.

How can I change my home directory back?  I've done some searching online, but all of the information I've been able to find so far is Cygwin-specific and hasn't translated well to MinGW/MSYS.

The most likely-looking avenues I've pursued so far are `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, both of which are entirely absent from MSYS' root.  I've tried creating an `/etc/nsswitch.conf` containing a `db_home: windows` line, but this seemed to have no effect.  I've not yet tried creating an `/etc/passwd` file as `mkpasswd` isn't present in MinGW/MSYS and I don't know what its contents should be.

I'm running:

- Windows 10 (w/ Anniversary Update)
- the latest version of all my installed MinGW and MSYS packages
- …including msys-mintty 1.0.3-1-msys-1.0.17

Comment: See also: [How to change HOME directory and start directory on MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33942924/4561887)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unlike Cygwin, MSYS relies on the `HOME` environment variable.  To set or change your `HOME` variable:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> on your keyboard or select "Run…" from the Start menu.
2. Type "sysdm.cpl" and click OK.
3. Select the Advanced tab and click Environment Variables…
4. Click New… to create a new `HOME` variable or select the existing one and click Edit…
5. When finished, keep clicking OK until all windows are closed.

Comment: I had tried just exporting the envvar in an existing terminal (it had a value that it pulled from who knows where), but MINGW still wouldn't use the new value it for some reason. Setting it through this method worked wonders though!

Comment: In MSYS2, this worked for shell, but did not work for ssh for some reason. nsswitch.conf way worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

The solution for MSYS2 is creating/updating `/etc/nsswitch.conf` with a line

```
db_home: windows
```

as described in Cygwin docs: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch-home.

After that all MSYS applications and terminals must be closed, as the configuration is only read once at MSYS DLL load time. (See https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch.)

As of Oct, 2019, it works for me in a fresh installation of MSYS2. Probably, in MSYS 1 `nsswitch.conf` was not supported.

Creating `HOME` environment variable works for shell, but does not work for `ssh`, which tries to access `/home/User/.ssh` anyway.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I set my `HOME` (`~`) dir to whatever I want in the seven MSYS2 terminals:

From my MSYS2 setup answer here: [Installing & setting up MSYS2 from scratch, including adding all 7 profiles to Windows Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407282/4561887):

> 1. Change your `HOME` (`~`) dir from MSYS2's default of `C:\msys64\home\my_username` to your regular Windows home dir of `C:\Users\my_username`:
>
>    Open up `C:\msys64\home\my_username\.bash_profile` in a text editor, such as VSCode. Modify it so that it looks like this. Note: you can just comment everything out with `#` and add this to the *top*:
>
>    ```bash
>    # Change your home (`~`) dir to `C:\Users\my_username`
>    HOME="/c/Users/$(whoami)"
>
>    # Source your `C:\Users\my_username\.profile` file, if it exists
>    if [ -f "$HOME/.profile" ]; then
>      . "$HOME/.profile"
>    fi
>    ```
>
>    Close and re-open Windows Terminal. Run `echo ~` and `echo "$HOME"` and ensure they now both show `/c/Users/my_username`. Run `ls -a` and ensure you see the contents of your normal Windows home directory for your user. `pwd` should show that you are currently in that directory too...